# Парсер товарных позиций. Указываю не правильно тэги?

Tags: python, парсер

Не получается выбрать названия позиций. Где неточность в коде?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_html(url):
    response = urllib.urlopen(url)
    return response.read()

def parse(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    table = soup.find('form', class_='box-katalog')

    projects = []

    for row in table.find_all('h2'):
        cols = row.find_all('h2')

        projects.append({
            'title': cols[0].a.alt
        })

    for projects in projects:
        print(projects)

def main():
    print(get_html('http://www.elix-c.ru/'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: А где Вы вызываете parse(), в коде нет вызова.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В разметке, у тэга `form` нет класса `box-katalog`, он у `div`.
Аргумент `class_` задается тот, который есть у тэга. Подробнее тут: [Searching by CSS class](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class)

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_html(url):
    response = urllib.urlopen(url)
    return response.read()

def parse(html):
    products = []
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    table = soup.find_all('div', class_='box-katalog')
    for row in table:
        for col in row.find_all('h2'):
            products.append({
                'title': col.text
            })

    for product in products:
        print(product['title'])

def main():
    html = get_html('http://www.elix-c.ru/')
    parse(html)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: выводит не все позиции

Comment: @titov_andrei, поправил, но думаю, это Вы и сами додумали